# Adobe Flash not supported in IE10, how can we fix this issue?

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

Is it true that IE10 and IE11 do not support Adobe Flash?
Can you help me to solve this issue?

I am trying to fix this issue, but I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah.. I fixed it.

By installing adobe flash18 version only ie.

and disabling the activex OBje